# Ajax call successful, but can't get radio values from $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My site is fully asynchronus, most of the html gets created and destroyed on button presses and every one of them prevents navigation.

At this part I produce a form with a "rate 1 to 10" array of radioboxes, post it using jQuery.ajax() and send it to process where it's either echoed back (for now) or echo "nothing was selected.".

This is the form,

```
<?php
<form id="surveyForm" action="processSurvey.php" method="post">

    <h3>Alimentos</h3>

    <h4>Sabor</h4>
    <div class="form-group">';
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            echo '
                <span class="lead form-options">' .'</span>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="sabor" id="saborRadio'. $i .'" value="'. $i .'">'. $i.'
                </label>';

        }
        echo '
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default surveyForm-btn" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>

</form>
?>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$('body').on('click', '.surveyForm', function(){
        console.log("Clicked on .surveyForm-btn");
        var data = $('#surveyForm').serialize();
        console.log( data );
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "processSurvey.php", 
            data: data, 
            success: function(result){
                console.log("Ajax call to processSurvey success");
                $("#surveyForm").clearForm();
                console.log(result);
                console.log( data );

            } 
        });
        return false;
    });
```

And this is the process php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sabor']))   // if ANY of the options was checked
  echo $_POST['sabor'];    // echo the choice
else
  echo "nothing was selected.";
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This is the console after clicking submit WITH a selected radiobox:

```
Clicked on #surveyForm
[EMPTY LINE]
Ajax call to processSurvey success
nothing was selected.
[EMPTY LINE]
```

This means the submit is successful, but the form data is empty. I've been trying to find the problem since yesterday,  I'm pretty sure I'm passing the data wrong but can't find anything in google that I haven't tried.

EDIT: Added most sugestions, problem persists. Maybe the html structure is wrong? The form and the submit don't seem to be connected.

EDIT 2: I found something very strange, on the final code there seems to be an extra closing tag, like this

```
<form id="surveyForm" action="processSurvey.php" method="post"></form>
    <h3>Alimentos</h3>
    <h4>Sabor</h4>
```

I have no idea where is that coming from, but is defenitely the problem.

Comment: You should do `if(isset($_POST['sabor']))`

Comment: radio buttons and checkboxes are only passed when they are set. Use `isset()`

Comment: You're creating multiple elements with `id=saborRadio`. IDs must be unique.

Comment: This is just a typo. `isset($_POST['radio'])` should be `isset($_POST['sabor'])`, like @pbolduc said.

Comment: I changed isset($_POST['radio']) trying to fix the code and forgot to change it back, the problem persists. Changing the classes for Id didn't help either.

Comment: Try to print the array post to see what you get in post

Comment: I used print_r($_POST); and it prints   
Array
(
)

Comment: Nothing is passed in post

Comment: Try doing console.log(data) in your javascript to see if your form is serialized

Comment: @pbolduc It just prints an empty line, I updated the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84628/discussion-between-tianrb-and-pbolduc).

Answer (score 2):

there are a lot of notes here

1- you will get confused with `form id='surveyForm'` and `button class='surveyForm'` so its better to change it a little bit to button class='surveyForm_btn'

2- I think you should serialize the form not the button

```
var data = $('#surveyForm').serialize(); // not .surveyForm
```

3- IDs must be unique

4- `$("#surveyForm").clearForm(); // not .surveyForm`

finally check all comments

and Its better to use

```
$('body').on('submit', '#surveyForm', function(){});
```

Edited answer:
1- please check everything after each step

```
<form id="surveyForm" action="processSurvey.php" method="post">
   <h3>Alimentos</h3>
   <h4>Sabor</h4>
   <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default surveyForm-btn" type="submit">Enviar</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

in js

```
$('body').on('submit', '#surveyForm', function(){
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "processSurvey.php", 
            data: data, 
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            } 
        });
        return false;
    });
```

in php

```
<?php
echo 'Connected successfully';
?>
```

this code will output Connected successfully in console .. if this work add your for loop and make a check again

Comment: Thanks for the answer! if I use $('body').on('submit', '#surveyForm', function(){ ... }); nothing seems to happen at all when I click. Maybe the form and the submit are disconnected somehow?

Comment: @TianRB I updated my answer for basic check .. please read it

Comment: Targeting #surveyForm on 'submit' prevents any console logs, as if I didn't click anything at all. 
Using .surveyForm-btn and 'click' behaves as described on the post.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yusef Since the html is created after load, using $('#surveyForm').on('submit',function(e){ ... won't attach the handler to the button, that's why i'm using $('body').on('click', '.surveyForm-btn', function(){ ... instead.

Comment: @TianRB you can use $(document).on('submit', '#surveyForm', function(e){ .... http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/o30nqt29/2/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousuf No changes either. I don't understand what can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your htm like that :

```
    <h3>Alimentos</h3>

    <h4>Sabor</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
<?php
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
         ?>
                <span class="lead form-options"></span>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="sabor" id="saborRadio<?=$i ?>" value="<?= $i ?>" /><?= $i?>
                </label>
<?php
        } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default surveyForm-btn" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could split loops like that! Thanks