# Jquery, PHP and AJAX - why is this not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code, but I can't get it to work. I want add.php to retrieve the follow var. I'm somewhat new to this and normally I can figure these things out myself or via a lot of googling, but this time I'm lost.

Jquery:

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ShowVideoAuthorFollow").click(function(){
        $.ajax({  
            var follow = <?php echo $row['memberid']; ?>;
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'add.php', 

            data: { follow:followw },
            success: function(response) {
                content.html(response);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
</SCRIPT>
```

add.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("connect.php");
$sql = "INSERT INTO following (m_id,following)
VALUES ('".$_SESSION['myuserid']."', '".$_POST['follow']."')";


if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

?>
```

Comment: put var follow = <?php echo $row['memberid']; ?>; before $.ajax and try again

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef tried it. Doesn't work either :/

Comment: just leave this line before the ajax .. and try to alert(response); inside success  and see what you will get

Comment: **SQL Injection Alert**. Do not use string concatenation for query construction.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef - See my "answer" please.

Comment: no need to post answer just edit your question .. anyway yes like that .. delete your answer

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709851/ajax-call-successful-but-cant-get-radio-values-from-post/31710108#31710108 and please follow steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Place **var follow** in the beginning
- If **$row['memberid']** is a String, then place it Inside quotes like **var follow = "<?php echo $row['memberid']; ?>";**
- Correct the spelling of **followw** to **follow** inside your AJAX
- What is **content.html(response)** ? Shouldn't it be **$("#content").html(response)** ?

  ```
  var follow = <?php echo $row['memberid']; ?>;

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#ShowVideoAuthorFollow").click(function(){

      $.ajax({  

        type: 'POST',  
        url: 'add.php', 
        data: { follow: follow },
        success: function(response) {

          $("#content").html(response);

        }

      });

    });

  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

taking a quick look, I found that you're trying to declare a variable inside a JSON object literal.

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ShowVideoAuthorFollow").click(function(){
        // move your var declaration here
        var follow = <?php echo $row['memberid']; ?>;
        $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'add.php', 

            data: { follow:followw },
            success: function(response) {
                content.html(response);
            }
        });

    });
});
</SCRIPT>
```